# Weird results with substr and mkdir function in php

Tags: php, file-upload, substr, mkdir

I have a fileupload with php but that's irrelevant because my real problem is that i have this code:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$real = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$finfo = pathinfo($real);
$time = time();
$rand1 = substr(sha1($real.$time),0,4);
$rand2 = substr(sha1($real.$time),5,-22);
$fname = preg_replace("#[^A-Za-z1-9]#","_", $_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
mkdir(UPLOAD_TO."/".$rand2,0777);
$targetFile = UPLOAD_TO."/".$rand2."/".$real;
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
   $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO files (realname,filename,extension,filesize,rand1,rand2,uppedby,created) VALUES(:real,:filename,:extension,:filesize,:rand1,:rand2,:uppedby,:created)");
$query->execute(array(
":real" => $real,
":filename" => $fname,
":extension" => $finfo['extension'],
":filesize" => filesize($tempFile),
":rand1" => $rand1,
":rand2" => $rand2,
":uppedby" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
":created" => time()
));

}
```

THe file is uploaded and i am creating an sha1 hash from the actual timestamp and the real filename. After i am cutting them with `substr()` but there is the tricky part. The mkdir is creating the directory not with the cutted string but with strange another combinations.
I don't know what i'm doing wrong. Could you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$rand2 = sha1(sha1($real.$time),0,4);`

this should be `$rand2 = substr(sha1($real.$time),0,4);` #RAND2

and please remove `$do = ;`

> ```
> Under "dev mod" an error would show up:
>
> Warning: sha1() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given
> ```

It's just you have a typo or something like that

**I made a quick check on my local server with such code and it works**

```
<?php
DEFINE('UPLOAD_TO',"C:/env/php/www/tests/");
if (!empty($_FILES))
{
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $real = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    $finfo = pathinfo($real);
    $time = time();
    $rand1 = substr(sha1($real.$time),0,4);
    $rand2 = substr(sha1($real.$time),5,-22);
    $fname = preg_replace("#[^A-Za-z1-9]#","_", $_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
    mkdir(UPLOAD_TO."/".$rand2,0777);
    $targetFile = UPLOAD_TO."/".$rand2."/".$real;
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}
?>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <input type="file" name="Filedata" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You could check it, but problem is your `sha1` function which should be replaced by `substr`

**Update 2**

As you have problems with your folder name and are unhappy with its name you can try changing `$rand2 = substr(sha1($real.$time),5,-22);` to `$rand2 = substr(sha1($real.$time),1,5);`

Read a manual of substr at [php.net substr](http://php.net/substr) and suit it to your needs, it's very basic by the way.

Three arguments of substr are `$STRING, $START and $LENGTH which is optional`. An excerpt from `php.net` might clear it all for you:

> If start is non-negative, the returned string will start at the
>   start'th position in string, counting from zero. For instance, in the
>   string 'abcdef', the character at position 0 is 'a', the character at
>   position 2 is 'c', and so forth.

In my opinion following part would clear your mind about it more **(pay attention to negative part)**

> If length is given and is positive, the string returned will contain
>   at most length characters beginning from start (depending on the
>   length of string).
>
> > If length is given and is negative, then that many characters will be
> >     omitted from the end of string (after the start position has been
> >     calculated when a start is negative). If start denotes the position of
> >     this truncation or beyond, false will be returned.

Comment: i have removed the `$do = ;` part but it's not solving the main issue

Comment: with three? why? on the php.net there are only 2 arguments max. http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php

Comment: it was only a typo now it's corrected and it seems like this
`$rand1 = substr(sha1($real.$time),0,4);
$rand2 = substr(sha1($real.$time),5,-22);`
and there is 1 parameter the `$real.$time`

Comment: but it isn't and that's why it's weird at all
the mkdir is creating a directory like this:
d8dabb010cfbe
but it should create a directory like this:
d8dabb
so, it's not really cutting the string or something like that

Comment: no, take a look at `$rand2` and change its substr method arguments to what you want it's from `5 to -22` now, try `1 and 5` for example

Comment: wow, and now it's good... interesting...
what was wrong with the `5 and -22`?

Comment: you have `start and end`. read this from documentation: `If start is non-negative, the returned string will start at the start'th position in string, counting from zero. For instance, in the string 'abcdef', the character at position 0 is 'a', the character at position 2 is 'c', and so forth.`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26344/discussion-between-rsz-and-dachi-n)